# No of independent components of Riemann tensor in $D=4$

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature, degrees-of-freedom

Using symmetric property between two indices and antisymmetric property between pair of indices we have 21 independent components. Also, using one cyclic sum condition over any three indices we finally have 20 components.

**My question** is why do not we consider the differential Bianchi identity as an added constraint on Riemann tensor?

Comment: I think you are abusing the term "independent". By independent components one usually means those components which are sufficient to recover the full tensor at a single given point. So, to answer your question - I would say, "by definition".

Comment: How would you do that? I do not see a way to use the second Bianchi identity to further reduce indipendent components of the tendor itself. The second Bianchi identity contains a cycle of covariant derivatives of the Riemann tensor, which means at best one would get very complicated differential equations for different components of the Riemann tensor.

Comment: 2nd Bianchi identity is a condition the  covariant derivatives must satisfy,it is not a condition to be satisfied by Riemann tensor itself.So it does not constrain the number of components of Riemann tensor as such. Right?

Comment: Yes I think one can phrase it like that. It is not an algebraic condition on the components of the Riemann tensor its a condition towards a combination of it's covariant derivatives.

Comment: Also how about the number of components of Einstein tensor, which is constructed with Riemann tensor and metric tensor? There are 2 components for Einstein tensor (using symmetricity in D=4 gives 10 components,along with 4 constraints from 1st Bianchi identity for Riemann tensor and 4 constraints from general coordinate transformation of the metric, leaving 2 components for Einstein tensor with 4 vacuum Einstein field equations to determine? Any clarification will be appreciated, please.